# Location Listener Not Working in Background

Tags: android, locationmanager

I am using this service to get Latitude and Longitude, but when i close the application I am not able to get the updated Latitude and Longitude.

here is my manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.kanwarpreet.location_manager">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".Activity_Location_Tracker">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".utils.MyService"
        android:process=":my_service"
        android:enabled="true"   />

</application>
</manifest>
```

Service Class

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "BOOMBOOMTESTGPS";
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;

private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
    Location mLastLocation;

    public LocationListener(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        Log.e("Location Changed", "Location Changed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
        mLastLocation.set(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}

LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER)
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
    initializeLocationManager();

    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[0]
        );
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[1]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[0]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
            try {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void initializeLocationManager() {
    Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}
}
```

Log cats when the application start's

```
05-22 12:35:53.754 10314-10322/? E/com.example.kanwarpreet.location_manager:my_service: Failed to send DDMS packet REAQ to debugger (-1 of 20): Broken pipe
05-22 12:35:54.048 10314-10314/? E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS: LocationListener gps
05-22 12:35:54.048 10314-10314/? E/Location Changed: Location Changed
05-22 12:35:54.048 10314-10314/? E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS: LocationListener network
05-22 12:35:54.048 10314-10314/? E/Location Changed: Location Changed
05-22 12:35:54.048 10314-10314/? E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS: LocationListener passive
05-22 12:35:54.048 10314-10314/? E/Location Changed: Location Changed
05-22 12:35:54.048 10314-10314/? E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS: onCreate
    initializeLocationManager
05-22 12:35:54.055 10314-10314/? E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS: onStartCommand
05-22 12:35:54.056 10314-10314/? E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS: onProviderDisabled: network
05-22 12:35:54.057 10314-10314/? E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS: onLocationChanged: Location[gps 33.000000,-127.000000 hAcc=20 et=+1h58m2s979ms alt=0.0 vAcc=??? sAcc=??? bAcc=??? {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=96]}]
05-22 12:35:54.058 10314-10314/? E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS: onStatusChanged: gps
05-22 12:35:54.059 10314-10314/? E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS: onLocationChanged: Location[gps 33.000000,-127.000000 hAcc=20 et=+1h58m2s979ms alt=0.0 vAcc=??? sAcc=??? bAcc=??? {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=96]}]
05-22 12:35:54.564 10314-10314/? E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS: onStatusChanged: gps
```

Logcat when I kill my application

```
05-22 12:37:03.069 10343-10343/com.example.kanwarpreet.location_manager:my_service E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS: LocationListener gps
05-22 12:37:03.069 10343-10343/com.example.kanwarpreet.location_manager:my_service E/Location Changed: Location Changed
05-22 12:37:03.069 10343-10343/com.example.kanwarpreet.location_manager:my_service E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS: LocationListener network
05-22 12:37:03.069 10343-10343/com.example.kanwarpreet.location_manager:my_service E/Location Changed: Location Changed
05-22 12:37:03.069 10343-10343/com.example.kanwarpreet.location_manager:my_service E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS: LocationListener passive
05-22 12:37:03.069 10343-10343/com.example.kanwarpreet.location_manager:my_service E/Location Changed: Location Changed
05-22 12:37:03.069 10343-10343/com.example.kanwarpreet.location_manager:my_service E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS: onCreate
    initializeLocationManager
05-22 12:37:03.072 10343-10343/com.example.kanwarpreet.location_manager:my_service E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS: onDestroy
05-22 12:37:03.073 10343-10343/com.example.kanwarpreet.location_manager:my_service E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS: onProviderDisabled: network
```

Comment: Change LocationListener class name  with different name

Comment: @ShivamKumar Nothing happen